# What is the maximum size of single `TEXT` data type time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to store my data in `TEXT` datatype in Apache IoTDB, but one time series may contain multiple fields of long-content data. So I wonder what is the upper limit of the size of the `TEXT` data type in Apache IoTDB? To see if the data I have now can be efficiently stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache IoTDB is able to store `TEXT` type of data in several mega size, so if your data size is smaller than this limit, IoTDB will be able to store your historical data for long period of time.